# Regex to match carriage return in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write some Javascript to hide some elements that contain only carriage returns. I appreciate that the correct way to solve this problem would be to stop these elements being created, but unfortunately that is not possible in this instance. I am trying to user a regular expression to search for the unwanted elements but am not having much luck. The function I have written is as follows:

```
function HideEmptyP()
{

    var patt = (\\r)
    for(var i = 0;i<desc[i].length;i++);
    {
    var desc[i] = document.getElementsByClassName('sitspagedesc');
    var result[i] = patt.test(desc[i]);
        if (result[i] == true)
            {
            desc[i].style.display='none';
            }
        else
            {
            alert("No Match!");
            }
    }
```

The error I'm getting in the Web Console is 'Syntax Error: Illegal Character'.

Grateful for any ideas on how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var patt = (\\r)` <== incorrect syntax

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am trying to write some Javascript to hide some elements that contain only carriage returns.

There's no need for a regular expression for that, just compare the element's `innerHTML` property to `"\\r"`, e.g.:

```
if (demo[i].innerHTML === "\\r") {
    // Remove it
}
```

But beware that some browsers may transform a single carriage return. You might want to check for `"\\r"`, `"\\n"`, and just a space. To do that, you *might* want to use a regular expression.

Your regular expression literal (`(\\r)`) is just completely invalid, it's worth [reading up on them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to learn the correct syntax. To write a regular expression literal in JavaScript, you use `/` as the delimiter. So: `/\\r/`. To test that a string contains only `\r`, `\n`, or space, you can use `/^[\r\n ]+$/` (which requires there be at least one character that matches, and uses `^` to indicate start-of-string, and `$` to indicate end-of-string):

```
if (demo[i].innerHTML.match(/^[\r\n ]+$/) {
    // Remove it
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Using the regular expression you suggested worked perfectly!

Comment: @AndyKaufman: No reason to apologize! I saw you were new, it's the only reason I mentioned it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting Syntax error is because the declaration 
var patt = (\r) 
is incorrect it should be somethign like var patt = '\r';

Also the whole for loop is wrong.

You should define demo before you start the for loop not inside it, and result need not be an array but just a normal variable

Answer (score 0):

Your litteral seems odd.

Try `var patt = /\r/;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var patt=/\n/gi
```

should work.

extra i flag to denote case insensitive.
g for global search.

Comment: /\n/gi is a regular expressions and it would try and find/replace all occurrences of \n in the string.