# javascript regex sms character count

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a javascript to count sms character in textarea. I would like to count few character as two characters e.g { } \ | [ ] € ^ include new line as two characters. I have written them into a regex. Please see code below.

```
ExChar = "\\^{}\\\\\\[~\\]|€\r\n"; 
ExCharRegExp = RegExp("^[\\" + ExChar + "]*$");
```

But when I execute the code it does not seem to work when I have newline/carriage return it still count as one character. May I know is there any issue with my code ? as I have followed this

[Regex to match carriage return in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527186/regex-to-match-carriage-return-in-javascript) the second answer talk about how to match \r\n

Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: ExCharRegExp = new RegExp("^[\\" + ExChar + "]*$"); still count "enter" as one character.

Comment: Any special reason it has to be a RegExp? Have a look at this question for a function to count SMS characters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454910/international-count-sms-characters/5456747#5456747

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is not reading the answer you are following.

It defines the regexp as a regexp literal `/^[\r\n ]+$/`, you define your regexp from a string literal.

The difference is the need to escape `\`. For your case you should write `\\r\\n`.

However, you might still get in trouble depending on how you handle the matches.

This is because `\r\n` matches two seperate characters.  A carriage return and a line feed - this is a legacy from the days of the typewriter.

An actual newline can, depending on the system, be represented as carriage return followed by a line feed, line feed followed by a carriage return, or just a line feed.